# What's the benefit of MODOK's forehead blazing?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-3, ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

In at least Marvel vs. Capcom 3 (and UMvC3), when MODOK hits someone with an "Analyze cube", power seems to be drawn to him from the impact and causes his forehead to blaze with a pink fire. It seems to power up certain moves of his. Is Analyze cube the only way to charge up? Which moves does it affect? What's its function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Analysis Cube](http://marvelvscapcom.wikia.com/wiki/Analysis_Cube)

> Analysis Cube (sometimes referred to as Analyze Cube) is one of M.O.D.O.K.'s special moves. M.O.D.O.K. summons a scientific virtual cube and when it hits its opponent, their energy is drained into the LED on M.O.D.O.K.'s forehead to increase the power of his Psionic Blaster.

---

> Analysis Cube adds a "LEVEL OF UNDERSTANDING" (LOU)

[Levels Of Understanding](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/MODOK_%28MvC3%29#Normal_Moves)

> LOUs make M.O.D.O.K specials and Hyper combos deal more damage and have
>   different effects. Different levels are shown via the flame on
>   M.O.D.O.K's headband. It goes from pink, to Violet, with an
>   increasingly larger flame as well.
>   - Can hold up to 9 LOUs
>   - Special moves use up 1 LOU, hypers use up all 9 of them

Special Moves affected by LOU

> Psionic Blaster - charged with LOU's
>   Jamming Bomb - Only available with LOU's
>   Giant Aegis Reflector -  Only available with LOU's. Size of giant Aegis depends upon LOU's

Hyper Moves affected by LOU

> Hyper Psionic Blaster  - charged with LOU's
>   Killer Illumination -  Its damage depends upon the number of LOU's
>   Limit Burst - Most likely LOU chargable

Comment: This answer is plagiarised from http://marvelvscapcom.wikia.com/wiki/Psionic_Blaster and other sources. Please cite your sources.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie was not my intention to plagiarize, I forgot to quote, now edited

Comment: I've formatted the cut-and-paste material as quotes

Comment: thanks @SevenSidedDie , i will learn from that and answer better next time. also who downvote please consider remove or upvote since  is an useful answer

Comment: The reason that I haven't accepted this answer is because the assertion that "collected data" only affects Psionic Blaster is untrue, from what I've seen which is corroborated by http://wiki.shoryuken.com/MODOK_%28MvC3%29#Normal_Moves.

Comment: @NiteCyper I edited the answer with the new data